# polygon floodfill

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

In Eagle Cad 6.4 is there a way to toggle between "real" and "outline" mode? The Ratsnest command will pour and display the flood fill. I simply want to return the display back to way it was prior,outline for easier visibility - Back and Forth.

I see that "ripup *" will do it. but it will also ripup the routes. In other CAD's one can simply redraw and the pour is simply omitted. 
I also see "SET POLYGON_RATSNEST OFF" will prevent the pours from filling. But does not un-draws the fills.

At the moment the only way I can see is to close and reopen the file.

Comment: I only know Eagle 5.x, but isn't performing a ripup by clicking on the edge of the filled polygon doing the trick?

Comment: @Rev1.0 That works in Eagle 6 too.

Comment: @us2012: Thanks for the confirmation, i posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a partial rip-up by clicking on the edge/perimeter of the filled polygon. This will just "clear" the polygon and leave everything else from the signal intact.

Answer (score 2):

"ripup @;" will clear the copper pour